# The homeomorphism between subspaces induced by a homeomorphism between the main spaces

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces such that $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic; let $A$ and $B$ be non-empty proper subsets of $X$ and $Y$, respectively. Suppose also that
$$ f(A) = B. \tag{1} $$
Then are the subspaces $X \setminus A$ and $Y \setminus B$ of $X$ and $Y$, respectively, also homeomorphic?

My Attempt:

> Let $f \colon X \longrightarrow Y$ be a homeomorphism of $X$ with $Y$. Then $f$ is a bijection. Moreover, for every open set $U$ of $X$, the image set $f(U)$ is open in $Y$; and for every open set $V$ of $Y$, the inverse image set $f^{-1}(V)$ is an open set of $X$.

> Since $f$ is bijective, we also have
> $$ 
> f( X \setminus A) = f(X) \setminus f(A) = Y \setminus f(A). 
> $$
> So if $B = f(A)$, then we have
> $$ f( X \setminus A) = Y \setminus B.$$

> Let the mapping $g \colon X \estminus A \longrightarrow Y \setminus B$ be defined by
> $$
> g(x) := f(x) \qquad \mbox{ for all } x \in X \setminus A. \tag{2} 
> $$
> This mapping $g$ is a bijection of $X \setminus A$ with $Y \setminus B$.

> Let $U$ be any open set of $X \setminus A$. Then we have
> $$
> U = (X \setminus A) \cap U_0
> $$
> for some open set $U_0$ of $X$. Moreover, we have
> \begin{align} 
> g (U) &= f(U) \\ 
> &= f \left( ( X \setminus A) \cap U_0 \right) \\ 
> &= f(X \setminus ) \cap f \left( U_0 \right) \\
> &= (Y \setminus B) \cap f \left( U_0 \right), 
> \end{align}
> which is open in the subspace $Y \setminus B$ because $f \left( U_0 \right)$ is open in $Y$.

> Similarly, if $V$ is an open set of $Y \setminus B$, then we have $V = (Y \setminus B) \cap V_0$ for soem open set $V_0$ of $Y$, and the set
> $$
> g^{-1} (V) = (X \setminus A) \cap f^{-1} \left( V_0 \right)
> $$
> is an open set of $X \setminus A$ because $f^{-1} \left( V_0 \right)$ is an open set of $X$.

Is the above proof satisfactory enough? Or, are there any lacunas in it?

Conversely, if $X \setminus A$ and $Y \setminus B$ are homeomorphic, then can we show that (1) above necessarily holds?

Comment: Who is $f$ in the question ? ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

- Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a homeomorphism.
- Let $A\subset X$ and $B:=f(A)$.
- Let $g \colon X \setminus A \to Y \setminus B$ and $h\colon A\to B$ be given by the formula $g(x)=f(x)$, $h(x)=f(x)$.

Then of course $g$ and $h$ are homeomorphisms. I don't went through all your proof, it seems correct, but the topological part can be proven much easier, since it's just a matter of restricting domain and codomain.

We can use the following fact, where $i_{A,X}\colon A\to X$ is an embedding.

**Fact.** Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces, $A\subset X$ and $B\subset Y$.
Consider any functions $f\colon X\to Y$, $g\colon X\to B$. Then

- $f|_A = f\circ i_{A,X}$ is continuous provided $f$ is continuous (we restrict the domain).
- $g$ is continuous iff $i_{B,Y}\circ g$ is continuous (we restrict the codomain).

Now return to our case. We have $g$ (as defined in the question) is continuous iff  $i_{Y\setminus B,Y}\circ g = f|_{X\setminus A}$ is continuous, which is true.

The last question is obvious. If $f$ and $g$ are homeomorphisms then $g(X\setminus A)=Y\setminus B$, so we can use the first part since $X\setminus(X\setminus A)=A$ and $X\setminus(X\setminus B)=B$.